# How to fetch all contacts using cursor and store it in strings to store them in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, android-studio

fetch all contacts using cursor and store it in strings to store them in firebase realtime database

```
 ArrayList<String> contactData=new ArrayList();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           try{
                String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null);
                  while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                       Firebase mRefchild = mRef.child(name);
                        mRefchild.setValue(phoneNumber);

                   }
                  phones.close();
```

Comment: please format your code and give description of your problem

Answer (score 1):

to get all Constact List

```
private void getContactList() { 
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null); 

    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                } 
                pCur.close();
            } 
        } 
    } 
    if(cur!=null){
        cur.close();
    } 
}
```

To save list or store list to firebase

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names"):
List nameList = new ArrayList<Type>(Arrays.asList(names));
// Now set value with new nameList 
ref.setValue(nameList)
```

Comment: i am a begginer... So please teel me exactly where to place **********Firebase ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names"):
List nameList = new ArrayList<Type>(Arrays.asList(names));
// Now set value with new nameList 
ref.setValue(nameList)**************** this code in your described code to fetch contacts.????